# "File (Field) Paths" and "Media" modules: files not saved in the intended folder

Tags: 7, files, media

I'm trying to use both the "[Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)" module (1.4) (to manage uploaded files) and the "[File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths)" (to keep the uploaded files organized in various subfolders).

Basically, I have a content type that has several taxonomy fields and a media field. The taxonomy fields are mandatory and accept only one value each. I want the media file to be uploaded in a folder that uses the various taxonomy fields as a path, and I've configured the file field accordingly (using the "file (field) paths" options). So the file should be saved to e.g.:

```
sites/default/files/documents/[taxonomy-term-1]/[taxonomy-term-2]/filename.extension
```

My problem is that, when manually creating a new node and adding a file to it, the file is just saved to the root of the public files directory:

```
sites/default/files/filename.extension
```

So the "file (field) paths" configuration for this field seems to be ignored. This also happens if I add a file *after* the node has been created and saved.
Since I expect the site will have a lot (thousands, maybe tens of thousands) of uploaded files, I fear that storing all of them in the same folder will have an impact on the performance of the site.

What's strange is that when I use the [feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import and create nodes in bulk (via a CSV file), the "file (field) paths" configuration is working as intended. The files are saved in the "complex" path.

So why wouldn't it work when creating a node manually?...
Any idea for a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've created an issue at drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/node/2358931

Answer (score 0):

No definitive answer so far, but I should note that I have been able to make this option work again simply by enabling the (very intimidating) option **"Active updating"** in the field's settings. (So in `admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/fields/[field-name]`)

The "File (Field) Paths" developer warns that *"This feature should only be used on developmental servers or with extreme caution"*, but since it's the only solution I've found so far, I'm going to keep this option enabled for now.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Update to File (Field) Paths >= 7.x-1.0-rc1 and issue is resolved.